# Converting jsonarray (having different type) to model array using JSONModel Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, jsonmodel

I have one problem in converting JSON array to model. I am using `JSONModel` library.

```
@protocol PTTemplateModel <NSObject>

@end

@protocol PTProfileTemplateModel <PTTemplateModel>

@end

@protocol PTCategoryTemplateModel <PTTemplateModel>

@end

    @interface PTTemplateModel : JSONModel
    @property (nonatomic, assign) TemplateType type;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* templateID; 
    @end

    @interface PTProfileTemplateModel : PTTemplateModel
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* logoURL;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* title;
    @end

    @interface PTCategoryTemplateModel : PTTemplateModel
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* category;
    @end

    @interface PTModel : JSONModel
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* title;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray< PTTemplateModel>* templates; // PTTemplateModel
```

Here `templates` array can have both `PTProfileTemplateModel` and `PTCategoryTemplateModel`.

JSON Input:

```
{"title":"Core","templates":[{"type":0,"templateID":"","logoURL":"", "title":"data"},{"type":1,"templateID":"","category":"DB"}]}
```

What I need is according to `type` I have to get `CategoryTemplate` or `ProfileTemplate`. But after conversion I am getting just `PTTemplateModel` type.

I know that I have specified protocol type as `PTTemplateModel`. But how do I get different type of model according to given data.

I tried:

1. `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray< PTTemplateModel>* templates;`
2. `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<PTProfileTemplateModel, PTCategoryTemplateModel>* templates;`
3. `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray< PTTemplateModel , PTProfileTemplateModel, PTCategoryTemplateModel>* templates;`

None of them works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try [BWJSONMatcher](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher), it helps you work with json data in a very very neat way:

```
@interface PTModel : NSObject<BWJSONValueObject>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *templates;
@end

@interface PTTemplateModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) TemplateType type;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *templateID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *logoURL;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *category;
@end
```

In the implementation of *PTModel*, implement the function **typeInProperty:** declared in protocol *BWJSONValueObject*:

```
- (Class)typeInProperty:(NSString *)property {
    if ([property isEqualToString:@"templates"]) {
        return [PTTemplateModel class];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Then you can use **BWJSONMatcher** to get your data model within one line:

```
PTModel *model = [PTModel fromJSONString:jsonString];
```

Detailed examples of how to use **BWJSONMatcher** can be found [here](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher/tree/master/BWJSONMatcherTests).